# Java: Printing Arraylist to Output File?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, filter

EDIT: To test these cases, change sort and filter methods to the following:

EXAMPLE SORT METHOD:

```
public void sortTitle() {
    Collections.sort(songs2, SongComparator.byTitle()); // now we have a sorted list
}
```

EXAMPLE FILTER METHOD (FOR STRING INPUT):

```
public void filterTitle(String s) {
    int n = 0;
    if (n == 0) {
        n++;
        for (Song song1 : songs2) {
            if ((!(((song1.title).contains(s))))) {
            itemsToRemove.add(song1);
            }
        }
        songs2.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
        itemsToRemove.clear();
    }
}
```

EXAMPLE FILTER METHOD (FOR INT INPUT):

```
public void filterRank(Range r) {
    int n = 0;
    if (n == 0) {
        n++;
        for (Song song1 : songs2) {
            if (song1.rank > (r.getMax()) || (song1.rank) < (r.getMin())) {
                itemsToRemove.add(song1);
            }
        }
        songs2.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
        itemsToRemove.clear();
    }
}
```

TEST CASES:

Input strings should be like the following examples:

```
sort:title
```

This input runs successfully until 
the line `System.setOut(out);` in the main class, where it begins to print spaces and does not successfully print the collection. This may be because of a problem with the toString method in the SongCollection class.

```
artist:Paramore
```

or

```
title:Misery Business
```

This input runs successfully through the entire program (the program does not terminate because the while loop does not terminate), except instead of printing the collection, a blank space is printed.

ADDITIONAL DETAILS:

This question is a followup to a previous question I asked, since I have short time constraints on this project (it is due tomorrow).
The primary problem I am experiencing with this is that the program is failing to output correctly, even though the methods and code in the main for printing seems logically sound.

[Printing arraylist into output file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586233/printing-arraylist-into-output-file/22596995?noredirect=1#comment34405711_22596995)

For some reason, it takes an extraordinary amount of time for the `ArrayLists` to be printed to the output file, usually 20-30 minutes. However, this only happens with the sort methods or the `filterTitle` or `filterArtist` methods (methods that concern String inputs).
When I run `filterRank` or `filterYear`, it runs perfectly fine.

When I print the `song2 ArrayList` directly from the filter methods, the only thing that is printed is `[]`, which means the `ArrayList` is empty, but it shouldn't be? And the `filterRank` and `filterYear` methods still work regardless of this.
Somehow I think it's related, though.

Input file can be found here: http://staff.rentonschools.us/hhs/ap-comp-science/projects/download/agazillionsongs.txt?id=223098

Full code for compilation:

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.util.*;
   import java.util.Comparator;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class GazillionSongs {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      System.out.println("Welcome to Java Song Collection!"); // greets the user
      System.out
      .println("This program sorts and filters large databases of popular songs."); // explains purpose of program
      System.out
      .println("This program is able to filter and sort by year, artist, title and rank.");
      System.out
      .println("Please enter a file that contains a database you wish to filter or sort. (i.e, alistofsongs.txt)"); // sample file = agazillionsongs.txt
      Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner which accepts filename
      String filename = fileInput.nextLine();

      File f = new File(filename); //creates file from input
      /*error check for file here*/
      Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(f); //inputs data from file

      ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
      while ((fileScanner.hasNextLine())) {
         songs.add(Song.parse(fileScanner.nextLine()));
      }

      System.out
      .println("Please select which commands you would like to use for the program.");
      System.out
      .println("Please format your command like the following example: year:<year(s)> rank:<rank(s)> artist:<artist> title:<title> sortBy:<field>");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("You may pick any number of commands you want.");
      System.out
      .println("For years and rank, you may select a range of years or ranks.");
      System.out
      .println("For artists and titles, you may enter a partial name or title.");
      System.out.println("i.e, year:1983 rank:1");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      while (input.hasNextLine()) {
         int n = 0;
         SongCollection collection = new SongCollection(songs);
         String inputType = input.nextLine();
         String delims = "[ ]";
         String[] tokens = inputType.split(delims);
         for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            n = 0;
            if (n == 0) {
               if ((tokens[i]).contains("year:")) {
                  collection.filterYear(Range.parse(tokens[i]));
                  n = 1;
               }// end of year loop
               if ((tokens[i]).contains("rank:")) {
                  collection.filterRank(Range.parse(tokens[i]));
                  n = 1;
               }// end of rank
               if ((tokens[i]).contains("artist:")) {
                  collection.filterArtist(tokens[i]);
                  n = 1;
               }// end of artist
               if ((tokens[i]).contains("title:")) {
                  collection.filterTitle(tokens[i]);
                  n = 1;
               }// end of title
               if ((tokens[i]).contains("sort:")) {
                     if ((tokens[i]).contains("title")) {
                        collection.sortTitle();
                        n = 1;
                     }// end of sort title
                     if ((tokens[i]).contains("artist")) {
                        collection.sortArtist();
                        n = 1;
                     }// end of sort artist
                     if ((tokens[i]).contains("rank")) {
                        collection.sortRank();
                        n = 1;
                     }// end of sort rank
                     if ((tokens[i]).contains("year")) {
                        collection.sortYear();
                        n = 1;
                     }// end of sort year
               }//end of sort
            }// end of for loop

         }// end of input.hasNextline loop
         final PrintStream console = System.out; //saves original System.out
         File outputFile = new File("output.txt"); //output file
         PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)); //new FileOutputStream
         System.setOut(out); //changes where data will be printed
         System.out.println(collection.toString());

         System.setOut(console); //changes output to print back to console
         Scanner outputFileScanner = new Scanner(outputFile); //inputs data from file
         while ((outputFileScanner.hasNextLine())) { //while the file still has data
            System.out.println(outputFileScanner.nextLine()); //print
         }
         outputFileScanner.close();
         out.close();
      }
   }// end of main
}// end of class

class Song{
   public enum Order {Year, Rank, Title, Artist}
   public int year;
   public int rank;
   public String artist;
   public String title;

   public static Song parse(String s) {
      Song instance = new Song();
      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, "\t");
      instance.year = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
      instance.rank = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
      instance.artist = (tokenizer.nextToken());
      instance.title = (tokenizer.nextToken());
      return instance;
   }

   public int getYear() {
      return year;
   }

   public int getRank() {
      return rank;
   }

   public String getArtist() {
      return artist;
   }

   public String getTitle() {
      return title;

   }

   public String toString() {
      String output = "\n\nYear = " + year + "\nRank = " + rank + "\nArtist = "
            + artist + "\nTitle = " + title;
      return output;
   }

}
class Range {
   private int min;
   private int max;

   public Range() {
      System.out.println("Please wait.");
   }

   public static Range parse(String s) {
      Range instance = new Range(); // instance is created here so object
                              // variables may be accessed
      String field; // String to contain deleted part of user input
      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, "-");
      StringTokenizer tokenizer2 = new StringTokenizer(s, ":");// for separating "field:" from the
                                                   // other part of the String
      if (s.contains(":")) { // this deletes the "field:" of the user input so
                        // it does not interfere with the parsing
         field = (tokenizer2.nextToken());
         s = s.replace(field, "");
         s = s.replace(":", "");
      }
      if (s.contains("-")) {
         instance.min = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
         instance.max = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());

      } else if (!(s.contains("-"))) {
         {
            instance.min = Integer.parseInt(s);
            instance.max = Integer.parseInt(s);
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Range max = " + instance.max);
      System.out.println("Range min = " + instance.min);
      return instance;
   }

   public boolean contains(int n) {
      if (n > min && n < max) { //if the number is contained in the range, method returns true.
         return true;
      } else if (n == min && n == max) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }

   public int getMin() {
      return min;
   }

   public int getMax() {
      return max;
   }
}
class SongCollection {
   ArrayList<Song> songs2;
   ArrayList<Song> itemsToRemove = new ArrayList<Song>(); // second collection
                                             // for items to
                                             // remove
   public SongCollection(ArrayList<Song> songs) { // constructor for SongCollection
      System.out.println("Test");
      this.songs2 = songs;
      }
   public void filterYear(Range r) {
      int n = 0;
      if (n == 0) {
         System.out.println("Program is processing.");
         n++;
         for (Song song1 : songs2) {
            if (song1.year > (r.getMax()) || (song1.year) < (r.getMin())) {
               itemsToRemove.add(song1);
            }
         }
         songs2.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
         itemsToRemove.clear();
      }
      System.out.println(songs2);
   }

   public void filterRank(Range r) {
      int n = 0;
      if (n == 0) {
         System.out.println("Program is processing.");
         n++;
         for (Song song1 : songs2) {
            if (song1.rank > (r.getMax()) || (song1.rank) < (r.getMin())) {
               itemsToRemove.add(song1);
            }
         }
         songs2.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
         itemsToRemove.clear();
      }
      System.out.println(songs2);
   }

   public void filterArtist(String s) {
      int n = 0;
      if (n == 0) {
         System.out.println("Program is processing.");
         n++;
         for (Song song1 : songs2) {
            if ((!(((song1.artist).contains(s))))) {
               itemsToRemove.add(song1);
            }
         }
         songs2.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
         itemsToRemove.clear();
      }
      System.out.println(songs2);
   }

   public void filterTitle(String s) {
      int n = 0;
      if (n == 0) {
         System.out.println("Program is processing.");
         n++;
         for (Song song1 : songs2) {
            if ((!(((song1.title).contains(s))))) {
            itemsToRemove.add(song1);
            }
         }
         songs2.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
         itemsToRemove.clear();
      }
      System.out.println(songs2);
   }

   public void sortTitle() {
        Collections.sort(songs2, SongComparator.byTitle()); // now we have a sorted list
        System.out.println(songs2);
      }
   public void sortRank() {
        Collections.sort(songs2, SongComparator.byRank()); // now we have a sorted list
        System.out.println(songs2);
      }
   public void sortArtist() {
        Collections.sort(songs2, SongComparator.byArtist()); // now we have a sorted list
        System.out.println(songs2);
      }
   public void sortYear() {
        Collections.sort(songs2, SongComparator.byYear()); // now we have a sorted list
        System.out.println(songs2);
      }
   public String toString() {
      String result = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < songs2.size(); i++) {
         result += " " + songs2.get(i);
      }

      return result;

   }
}
class SongComparator implements Comparator<Song> {
   public enum Order{
      YEAR_SORT, RANK_SORT, ARTIST_SORT, TITLE_SORT
   }
   private Order sortingBy;
   public SongComparator(Order sortingBy){
      this.sortingBy = sortingBy;
   }
   public static SongComparator byTitle() {
       return new SongComparator(SongComparator.Order.TITLE_SORT);
   }
   public static SongComparator byYear() {
       return new SongComparator(SongComparator.Order.YEAR_SORT);
   }
   public static SongComparator byArtist() {
       return new SongComparator(SongComparator.Order.ARTIST_SORT);
   }
   public static SongComparator byRank() {
       return new SongComparator(SongComparator.Order.RANK_SORT);
   }

   @Override
   public int compare(Song song1, Song song2) {
      switch (sortingBy) {
      case YEAR_SORT:
         return Integer.compare(song1.year, song2.year);
      case RANK_SORT:
         return Integer.compare(song1.rank, song2.rank);
      case ARTIST_SORT:
         return song1.artist.compareTo(song2.artist);
      case TITLE_SORT:
         return song1.title.compareTo(song2.title);
      }
      throw new RuntimeException(
            "Practically unreachable code, can't be thrown");
   }

}
```

Comment: I misunderstood the time constraints in the OP's original question, and suggested he post it anew. My answer was focused on longer term fixes, not knowing it's an assignment due tomorrow. I am going out and don't have time to address it further. There is a lot of code at the bottom, but that is *only for the purpose of having a fully-compilable class*, in order to make it easier for us to help him--everything above it is to help us focus on the specific problem. Please consider helping. He's taken every suggestion I've made to heart, as far as how to improve his question. Thanks.

Comment: I hope you have found the solution you are looking for. At the very least, you now know how to write a great question. Just make it clear that the "extra code" is not to distract but to help, and *minimize its presence*, meaning put it all in a single block, instead of one block per class. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run this code and it works fine and fast. I am using file you posted and as you can see, test value for searching is "year:1983 sort:title". I also simplified it by removing while-cycle and user-input filename and filter string, so anyone can easily reproduce it.

If you want to help, I need to know, how to reproduce that 20-30 minute outputing to file.
 :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class GazillionSongs {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Java Song Collection!"); // greets the user
        System.out
                .println("This program sorts and filters large databases of popular songs."); // explains purpose of program
        System.out
                .println("This program is able to filter and sort by year, artist, title and rank.");
        System.out
                .println("Please enter a file that contains a database you wish to filter or sort. (i.e, alistofsongs.txt)"); // sample file = agazillionsongs.txt

        File f = new File("agazillionsongs.txt"); //creates file from input
      /*error check for file here*/
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(f); //inputs data from file

        List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
        while ((fileScanner.hasNextLine())) {
            Song song = Song.parse(fileScanner.nextLine());
            songs.add(song);
        }

        System.out
                .println("Please select which commands you would like to use for the program.");
        System.out
                .println("Please format your command like the following example: year:<year(s)> rank:<rank(s)> artist:<artist> title:<title> sortBy:<field>");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You may pick any number of commands you want.");
        System.out
                .println("For years and rank, you may select a range of years or ranks.");
        System.out
                .println("For artists and titles, you may enter a partial name or title.");
        System.out.println("i.e, year:1983 rank:1");

        int n = 0;
        SongCollection collection = new SongCollection(songs);
        String inputType = "year:1983 sort:title";
        String delims = "[ ]";
        String[] tokens = inputType.split(delims);
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            n = 0;
            if (n == 0) {
                if ((tokens[i]).contains("year:")) {
                    collection.filterYear(Range.parse(tokens[i]));
                    n = 1;
                }// end of year loop
                if ((tokens[i]).contains("rank:")) {
                    collection.filterRank(Range.parse(tokens[i]));
                    n = 1;
                }// end of rank
                if ((tokens[i]).contains("artist:")) {
                    collection.filterArtist(tokens[i]);
                    n = 1;
                }// end of artist
                if ((tokens[i]).contains("title:")) {
                    collection.filterTitle(tokens[i]);
                    n = 1;
                }// end of title
                if ((tokens[i]).contains("sort:")) {
                    if ((tokens[i]).contains("title")) {
                        collection.sortTitle();
                        n = 1;
                    }// end of sort title
                    if ((tokens[i]).contains("artist")) {
                        collection.sortArtist();
                        n = 1;
                    }// end of sort artist
                    if ((tokens[i]).contains("rank")) {
                        collection.sortRank();
                        n = 1;
                    }// end of sort rank
                    if ((tokens[i]).contains("year")) {
                        collection.sortYear();
                        n = 1;
                    }// end of sort year
                }//end of sort
            }// end of for loop

        }// end of input.hasNextline loop
        final PrintStream console = System.out; //saves original System.out
        File outputFile = new File("output.txt"); //output file
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)); //new FileOutputStream
        System.setOut(out); //changes where data will be printed
        System.out.println(collection.toString());

        System.setOut(console); //changes output to print back to console
        Scanner outputFileScanner = new Scanner(outputFile); //inputs data from file
        while ((outputFileScanner.hasNextLine())) { //while the file still has data
            System.out.println(outputFileScanner.nextLine()); //print
        }
        outputFileScanner.close();
        out.close();
    }
}// end of main

class Song {

    public enum Order {

        Year, Rank, Title, Artist
    }
    public int year;
    public int rank;
    public String artist;
    public String title;

    public static Song parse(String s) {
        Song instance = new Song();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, "\t");
        instance.year = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        instance.rank = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        instance.artist = (tokenizer.nextToken());
        instance.title = (tokenizer.nextToken());
        return instance;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String output = "\n\nYear = " + year + "\nRank = " + rank + "\nArtist = "
                + artist + "\nTitle = " + title;
        return output;
    }

}

class Range {

    private int min;
    private int max;

    public Range() {
        System.out.println("Please wait.");
    }

    public static Range parse(String s) {
        Range instance = new Range(); // instance is created here so object
        // variables may be accessed
        String field; // String to contain deleted part of user input
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, "-");
        StringTokenizer tokenizer2 = new StringTokenizer(s, ":");// for separating "field:" from the
        // other part of the String
        if (s.contains(":")) { // this deletes the "field:" of the user input so
            // it does not interfere with the parsing
            field = (tokenizer2.nextToken());
            s = s.replace(field, "");
            s = s.replace(":", "");
        }
        if (s.contains("-")) {
            instance.min = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            instance.max = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());

        } else if (!(s.contains("-"))) {
            {
                instance.min = Integer.parseInt(s);
                instance.max = Integer.parseInt(s);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Range max = " + instance.max);
        System.out.println("Range min = " + instance.min);
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean contains(int n) {
        if (n > min && n < max) { //if the number is contained in the range, method returns true.
            return true;
        } else if (n == min && n == max) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }
}

class SongCollection {

    List<Song> songs2;
    List<Song> itemsToRemove = new ArrayList<Song>(); // second collection
    // for items to
    // remove

    public SongCollection(List<Song> songs) { // constructor for SongCollection
        System.out.println("Test");
        this.songs2 = songs;
    }

    public void filterYear(Range r) {
        int n = 0;
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println("Program is processing.");
            n++;
            for (Song song1 : songs2) {
                if (song1.year > (r.getMax()) || (song1.year) < (r.getMin())) {
                    itemsToRemove.add(song1);
                }
            }
            songs2.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
            itemsToRemove.clear();
        }
        System.out.println(songs2);
    }

    public void filterRank(Range r) {
        int n = 0;
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println("Program is processing.");
            n++;
            for (Song song1 : songs2) {
                if (song1.rank > (r.getMax()) || (song1.rank) < (r.getMin())) {
                    itemsToRemove.add(song1);
                }
            }
            songs2.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
            itemsToRemove.clear();
        }
        System.out.println(songs2);
    }

    public void filterArtist(String s) {
        int n = 0;
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println("Program is processing.");
            n++;
            for (Song song1 : songs2) {
                if ((!(((song1.artist).contains(s))))) {
                    itemsToRemove.add(song1);
                }
            }
            songs2.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
            itemsToRemove.clear();
        }
        System.out.println(songs2);
    }

    public void filterTitle(String s) {
        int n = 0;
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println("Program is processing.");
            n++;
            for (Song song1 : songs2) {
                if ((!(((song1.title).contains(s))))) {
                    itemsToRemove.add(song1);
                }
            }
            songs2.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
            itemsToRemove.clear();
        }
        System.out.println(songs2);
    }

    public void sortTitle() {
        Collections.sort(songs2, SongComparator.byTitle()); // now we have a sorted list
        System.out.println(songs2);
    }

    public void sortRank() {
        Collections.sort(songs2, SongComparator.byRank()); // now we have a sorted list
        System.out.println(songs2);
    }

    public void sortArtist() {
        Collections.sort(songs2, SongComparator.byArtist()); // now we have a sorted list
        System.out.println(songs2);
    }

    public void sortYear() {
        Collections.sort(songs2, SongComparator.byYear()); // now we have a sorted list
        System.out.println(songs2);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < songs2.size(); i++) {
            result += " " + songs2.get(i);
        }

        return result;

    }
}

class SongComparator implements Comparator<Song> {

    public enum Order {

        YEAR_SORT, RANK_SORT, ARTIST_SORT, TITLE_SORT
    }
    private Order sortingBy;

    public SongComparator(Order sortingBy) {
        this.sortingBy = sortingBy;
    }

    public static SongComparator byTitle() {
        return new SongComparator(SongComparator.Order.TITLE_SORT);
    }

    public static SongComparator byYear() {
        return new SongComparator(SongComparator.Order.YEAR_SORT);
    }

    public static SongComparator byArtist() {
        return new SongComparator(SongComparator.Order.ARTIST_SORT);
    }

    public static SongComparator byRank() {
        return new SongComparator(SongComparator.Order.RANK_SORT);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Song song1, Song song2) {
        switch (sortingBy) {
            case YEAR_SORT:
                return Integer.compare(song1.year, song2.year);
            case RANK_SORT:
                return Integer.compare(song1.rank, song2.rank);
            case ARTIST_SORT:
                return song1.artist.compareTo(song2.artist);
            case TITLE_SORT:
                return song1.title.compareTo(song2.title);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Practically unreachable code, can't be thrown");
    }

}
```

EDIT :

Question:

---

```
title:Misery Business
```

This input runs successfully through the entire program (the program does not terminate because the while loop does not terminate), except instead of printing the collection, a blank space is printed.

---

Yes, because in your method, you are testing, if it contains `title:Misery Business` not `Misery Business`.

First of all, you cant use that tokenizer for anything, that contains space. But for one-word only, you can change it as following :

Tested and working for `title:Misery` :

```
public void filterTitle(String s) {
    int n = 0;
    s = s.split(":")[1];
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println("Program is processing.");
        n++;
        for (Song song1 : songs2) {
            if (song1.title.contains(s) == false) {
                itemsToRemove.add(song1);
            }
        }
        songs2.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
        itemsToRemove.clear();
    }
    System.out.println(songs2);
}
```

Comment: I also tried : "title:Fever", still working fast (not fine, cause you are looking for String `title:Fever`, not only `Fever`, so it does not find anything, however it is working fast)

Comment: Did you test it without the println() statements in the sort methods? That's when it doesn't print anything for me.

Comment: @user3450277 - I do not understand what exactly you want me to do. Just edit your post and add there an example, which is copy-and-paste (you can use what I have) and which reproduce your long-saving. If we are not able to reproduce it, we are not able to help you.

Comment: Okay, I have added more details. Please tell me if there is anything else that would help.

Comment: @user3450277 - edited, but still no signs of 20-30 minutes saving issue.

Comment: The "saving" issue happens when you run the methods. :/ Did you test either of the cases?

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it is really 20-30 minutes, these are the problems I'm having...so I honestly don't know what else to say.

Comment: @user3450277 - just give me the code, I copy-paste-run and it will reproduce that 20-30 minute saving.

Just now, I tried what you say (using title:Misery) and it is working fast and fine.